# How would I show that this sequence of functions is increasing?

Tags: calculus, sequence-of-function

> Show that the continuously differentiable sequence $N_n(x)$ is increasing, where
>   $$N_n(x)=N(nx),\,\, \frac{d}{dx}N(x)\geq0\,\,\forall x,\,\,\,N(x)=0\,\,\forall x\leq 0, \,\, N(x)=1\,\,\forall x\geq 1$$

I tried to prove this using induction but it did not lead me anywhere. Specifically, I stated that since $N’(x)\geq 0$ then assuming it is true for $n$ it follows that $ \frac{d}{dx}N((n+1)(x))= nN’((n+1)(x))+N’((n+1)(x))$, but I am not sure how to show that this is non-negative.

I am not sure whether the given statement is effectively true because if I define the sequence as follows:
$$N_n(x):=\begin{cases}
(-1)^n+1,\,\,& x\leq 0\\
g(nx)\,\,&0<x<1\\
(-1)^{n+1}\,\,&x\geq 1
\end{cases}$$
and $g(nx)$ is defined to be increasing for $n$ odd and decreasing for $n$ even, then this specific definition of $N_n(x)$ shows that it is not true that $N_{n+1}(x) \geq N_n(x)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Positive derivative means that $N(x)$ is non-decreasing. Then $N_n(x) = N(nx) \leq N((n+1)x) = N_{n+1}(x)$. For positive $x$ it's just the use of the fact that $N$ is non-decreasing. For negative, everything is $0$.

Comment: @Jakobian yes, but that would hold for $n=1$ (i.e. $N_1(x)=N(x)$), how do you know it holds for $n>1$? Because the problem does not state that $N_n’(x)\geq 0$

Comment: @Jakobian Also, you say that for negative $x$ $N$ is zero, but, again, wouldn’t that only be true for when $n=1$... based on the problem statement, and may not be necessarily true for all $n$? This is where my confusion arises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method of defining $N_n$ is confused : according to the constraints, once $N(x)$ is defined, $N_n(x)$ is defined for all $n$ -- it's $N_n(x) = N(nx)$.

Note that $N(x) = 0$ for all $x \leq 0$, so $N_n(x) = N(nx) = 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb{Z}_{>0}$ and all $x \leq 0$.  Consequently, since your proposed $N_n(x)$ is $(-1)^n + 1$ on $x \leq 0$, your proposed $N_n$ does not meet the given constraints.  Similarly, the constraints force $N_n(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 1/n$, so your proposed $N_n$ does not meet the constraints on that piece of the function.

In fact, $N_n$ is a [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) with (closed) support (a closed subset of) $[0,1/n]$.

More to your question, $N_n'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} N(n x) = n N'(n x) \geq 0$ (because $nx$ is just some real number).  So each $N_n(x)$ is increasing along $x$.

Furthermore, $N_{n+1}(x) - N_n(x) = N((n+1)x) - N(n x)$.  For $x \leq 0$, this difference is $0$.  For $x > 0$, the mean value theorem shows there is a point, $c$ between $nx$ and $(n+1)x$ where $N'(c) \geq 0$ is the same as the average rate of change of $N$ between $nx$ and $(n+1)x$, so $N_n(x)$ is also increasing along $n$.